# Remove one of the two consecutive escape characters in R

Tags: r, regex

I have following sentence where \n characters appear

```
Get to 6 month rolling\nemail (from 13 months)\n\nOngoing work with Firm...
```

and I need to remove one of the two consecutive so desire output should look like:

```
Get to 6 month rolling\nemail (from 13 months)\nOngoing work with Firm...
```

so that \n\nOngoing looks like \nOngoing. Is there any simple way how to do that in R. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's one of way

```
> gsub("\n\n", "\n", "Get to 6 month rolling\nemail (from 13 months)\n\nOngoing work with Firm")
[1] "Get to 6 month rolling\nemail (from 13 months)\nOngoing work with Firm"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot it could be so simple :-)